# What happened if a TestFlight session did not end with a "Session ended" log?

Tags: ios, testflight

In TestFlight, when you check out a session's logs, usually it will be of the form

```
2014-01-04 21:18:47 TestFlight: Started Session
... Went to the forest...
... Looking for monster ...
... Found a monster...
2014-01-04 21:21:24 TestFlight: Ending Session
```

I have around 10 testers and their sessions are all of the same form as above.

There is one particular tester who claims that the app is crashing.

However, there is no crash report. So then I decided to look at his session logs to find a clue.

I noticed something odd about his logs: they ended **suddenly** without the "Ending Session" message. His logs were like this:

```
2014-01-04 21:18:47 TestFlight: Started Session
... Went to the forest...
... Looking for monster ...
```

And that's it. It seems to be cut or something.

This is what I was expecting:

```
2014-01-04 21:18:47 TestFlight: Started Session
... Went to the forest...
... Looking for monster ...
... CRASHED! ...
2014-01-04 21:21:24 TestFlight: Ending Session
```

But no, instead the log seems to be suddenly cut off.

What may have caused this? Whenever the game crashes for someone, I get

- A crash report
- A session log that goes from start to finish, including the crashing part

But I don't get either of those. Instead, I get an incomplete session log.

One would guess that the culprit is what happens after `Looking for monster`, but the thing is, he says that the app crashed multiple times already, and when I look at the many (incomplete) logs, they are all cut in different parts - seemingly random.

So, what does this mean? What could be causing a crash to go unreported AND an incomplete session log? (They are incomplete because there is no "Session Ended" message like they usually have).

It has happened only with this user. None of the other 9 had this problem.

He does have a device that the others are not using though: a 4th generation iPod touch with 6.1.5 iOS. Everyone else is using an iPhone 4+ or iPads. Not sure if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

If an app with the TestFlight SDK crashes, the SDK will try to send the sessions before the app exits out, but if they are not sent in time, the sessions will be sent the next time the app is started. In your case, it appears that the start session was sent, but the SDK wasn't able to send the crash and end session on time.

I tested the SDK on an iPod touch 4th gen (6.1.5) and there doesn't appear to be any issues with crash reporting. Were you able to receive crash reports from other builds? Are you using any other crash handlers in your app?

If you haven't already, please make sure that you're using the latest TestFlight SDK.
https://testflightapp.com/sdk

If you continue to have problems, please contact TestFlight support with the URL to the build's sessions page. http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/emails/new